# Why Command Pattern when a client can call the method directly from reciever instance?

Tags: design-patterns, command-pattern

Recently I have come across `Command Pattern`. In this pattern Client is responsible for creating the instances of Reciever, ConcreteCommand and Invoker. At some point of time (Lets say that in a Button Click) Invoke method of Invoker is being called. Now the Invoke method is responsible for executing a particular operation in Reciever. But Why do I need an Invoker ( Otherwise Command Pattern) when the client can directly call the particular action using Reciever?

Comment: Have a look at this example : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35276941/how-commnd-pattern-decouples-the-sender-from-reciever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why do I need an Invoker (Command Pattern) when the client can
>   directly call the particular action using Reciever?

This is the one of the main design rationales of the Command Pattern - [decouple](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decoupling#Software_Development) an invoker from a receiver (sender-receiver / produced-consumer).