# How does the Command pattern decouple the sender from the receiver?

Tags: java, design-patterns, command-pattern

The Command pattern has an IReceiver interface with few methods and corresponding to  each method there are concrete Command objects (implementing an interface `ICommand` with execute() method).

I have read that the client knows about the concrete receiver and concrete command and it is usually the client setting up the receiver object in the concrete command object. Then why it is said it decouples the sender and the receiver?

When the client already knows the concrete receiver then I feel this is not loose coupling and also the client in this case can directly call the APIs (methods) on the receiver object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can think of Command pattern workflow as follows.

1. `Command` declares an interface for all commands, providing a simple execute() method which asks the Receiver of the command to carry out an operation.
2. The `Receiver` has the knowledge of what to do to carry out the request.
3. The `Invoker` holds a command and can get the `Command` to execute a request by calling the execute method.
4. The `Client` creates `ConcreteCommands` and sets a `Receiver` for the command.
5. The `ConcreteCommand` defines a binding between the action and the receiver.
6. When the `Invoker` calls execute the `ConcreteCommand` will run one or more actions on the Receiver.

Have a look at sample code to understand things in better way.

```
public class CommandDemoEx{
    public static void main(String args[]){

        // On command for TV with same invoker 
        Receiver r = new TV();
        Command onCommand = new OnCommand(r);
        Invoker invoker = new Invoker(onCommand);
        invoker.execute();

        // On command for DVDPlayer with same invoker 
        r = new DVDPlayer();
        onCommand = new OnCommand(r);
        invoker = new Invoker(onCommand);
        invoker.execute();

    }
}
interface Command {
    public void execute();
}

class Receiver {
    public void switchOn(){
        System.out.println("Switch on from:"+this.getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
}

class OnCommand implements Command{

    private Receiver receiver;

    public OnCommand(Receiver receiver){
        this.receiver = receiver;
    }
    public void execute(){
        receiver.switchOn();
    }
}

class Invoker {
    public Command command;

    public Invoker(Command c){
        this.command=c;
    }
    public void execute(){
        this.command.execute();
    }
}

class TV extends Receiver{
    public TV(){

    }
    public String toString(){
        return this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    }
}
class DVDPlayer extends Receiver{
    public DVDPlayer(){

    }
    public String toString(){
        return this.getClass().getSimpleName();
    }
}
```

output:

```
java CommandDemoEx
Switch on from:TV
Switch on from:DVDPlayer
```

To answer your question :

> I have read client knows about the concrete receiver and concrete command and it is usually client setting up the receiver object in the concrete command object. Then why it is said it decouples the sender and the receiver

To standardize the words, replace "sender" with "invoker". Now go through the code.

1. ***`Invoker simply executes the ConcreteCommand`*** (OnCommand in this case)  by passing ConcreteReceiver.
2. ***`ConcreteCommand executes Command`***  through ConcreteReceiver i.e. `ConcreteCommand defines binding between Action and Receiver.`
3. If you see the workflow, Invoker does not change with additional commands and you can add business logic in `execute()` method of Invoker like java.lang.Thread, which has been explained as below.
4. In this way ***`Client (sender) and Receiver are loosely couple through Invoker, which has knowledge of  what command to be executed`***.

***Thread example*** from this [link](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Thread.java/?v=source)

You can create Thread by implementing Runnable object.

```
Thread t = new Thread (new MyRunnable()).start();
```

=>

```
 Invoker invoker = new Invoker(new ConcreteCommand());
 invoker.start()
```

*and you have logic in start() to call ConcreteCommand.execute() which is run() in above case.*

***start() method will call run() method in Thread. What happens if you directly call run() method directly? It won't be treated as thread***.

Like start() method of this thread, you can add some business logic in Invoker.

```
public synchronized void start() {
        /**
         * This method is not invoked for the main method thread or "system"
         * group threads created/set up by the VM. Any new functionality added
         * to this method in the future may have to also be added to the VM.
         *
         * A zero status value corresponds to state "NEW".
         */
        if (threadStatus != 0)
            throw new IllegalThreadStateException();
        group.add(this);
        start0();
        if (stopBeforeStart) {
            stop0(throwableFromStop);
        }
    }

private native void start0(); // Native code is not here but this method will call run() method

public void run() {
    if (target != null) {
        target.run();
    }
}
```

***EDIT:***

On your last query

> Here we are creating the command object, Receiver object and Invoker Object.Then passing the receiver object in the command object and then passing the command object in invoker object. This we do for each Receiver like we do here for TV and DVDPlayer. Also in the method 'main' Object of TV and DVDPlayer are known and in fact are created. We can simply do tvObject.switchOn() and dvdPlayer.switchOn(). How does Command pattern help

Client  need not worry about changes in `Receiver` class. `Invoker` directly works on `ConcreteCommand`, which has `Receiver` object. `Receiver` object may change `siwtchOn`() to `switchOnDevice`() in future. But client interaction does not change.

If you have two different commands like `switchOn`() and `switchOff`(), still you can use same `Invoker`.

Comment: Thanks Ravindra for answering, but still I am not clear. I want to clear my understanding on as how Command pattern is helpful. Here we are  creating the command object, Receiver object and Invoker Object.Then passing the receiver object in the command object and then passing the command object in invoker object. This we do for each Receiver like we do here for TV and DVDPlayer.  Also in the method 'main' Object of TV and DVDPlayer are known and in fact are created. We can simply do tvObject.switchOn() and dvdPlayer.switchOn(). How does Command pattern help.

Comment: If switchOn  was changed to switchDevice later, client does not require any changes if that command is executed from ConcreteCommand. Like switchOn, you can have switchOff command and can use same invoker for  both on and off commands.

Comment: please refer http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/120029/command-pattern-for-non-related-recievers-in-java-with-command-execute-and-undo I have implemented the Command pattern as per my understanding after studying Command pattern and the comments here. It would be nice to have your review comments over there...

Comment: Updated my comments in that question. Linked this question there :)

Comment: ' Client need not worry about changes in Receiver class. .....  Receiver object may change `siwtchOn()` to `switchOnDevice()` in future. But client interaction does not change. ' - if the receiver object  changes `siwtchOn()` to `switchOnDevice()` , then the client need not worry about the change. But the `Concretecommand` needs to know it, right ? If yes, then what benefits do you point at here ?

Answer (score 3):

Directly from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern):

> The command pattern is a behavioral design pattern in which an object is used to encapsulate all information needed to perform an action or trigger an event at a later time.

**Edit**

After re-reading the [Gang of Four](http://www.uml.org.cn/c++/pdf/DesignPatterns.pdf)'s section on the Command pattern, I thought up a better scenario. Let's say you have a GUI library, which defines the following:

```
public interface Command {
    public void execute();
}

public class Button {
    private Command command;

    public Button(Command command) {
        this.command = command;
    }

    public void click() {
        command.execute();
    }
}
```

The Button, in this case, is the receiver of a command, and your code, that creates actual instances of Buttons, is the client. Of course, when you create a button, you have to define some concrete implementations of the `Command` interface. But the GUI library does not need to know about these classes; all it needs is the interface. This is how the GUI code is decoupled from your code.

Comment: thanks Andrew for the answer. Sorry but still I am not too clear on this.  Can you please give a small example as how if command pattern is not used then things become difficult to manage or complexcity is increased or code duplication or any other ill effect if command pattern is not used...

Comment: @nits.kk See the edit, I hope it makes more sense. The main idea is that implementation is hidden behind the Command interface, so you don't end up with multiple classes when you only need one. E.g. a `RefreshButton` and an `UndoButton` could just be a plain `Button`, with different `Command`s to execute.

Comment: Impressive explanation Andrew.. n thanks for the efforts. But I feel above is more like observer pattern.  In the above explanation, its more like callback some what miniature form of observer pattern. Here in the example, Command is like an observer registered in the button class. Upon click the call back method 'execute' is called and in the concrete implementation of 'execute()' method actual operations like refresh, undo can be performed. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong...

Comment: Yes, design patterns often have a lot of overlap. This also shows a lot of the features of *Strategy*, where the actual implementation is hidden behind an interface. The thing that makes *Command* special is that each command object holds all the information it needs to perform the action. This example doesn't really show that so much, you wanted to see how it *decouples* code. This was the simplest way I could show it.

Answer (score 1):

### Loose coupling isn't the main goal of Command

Here's the class diagram for the Command pattern from the original [Design Patterns book](http://www.amazon.ca/Design-Patterns-Elements-Reusable-Object-Oriented/dp/0201633612):

[image: Command class diagram]

As you said, `Client` knows about the `ConcreteCommand` and the `Receiver`, so there's not decoupling there.

> why it is said it decouples the sender and the receiver

My copy of the book doesn't say that's the goal of the Command pattern:

> Encapsulate a request as an object, thereby letting you parameterize clients with different requests, queue or log requests, and support undoable operations.

Andrew's answer touches on the fact that the *logic thread* is decoupled from the commands. You can maybe better see the loose coupling between `Invoker` and `Command` when you refer to the sequence diagram of the pattern described in the Design Patterns:

[image: Command sequence diagram]

Many design patterns define a Client that is loosely coupled from the variations (e.g., Visitor, Strategy, Observer, Iterator, etc.). Loose coupling is a benefit to maintainability, so-called design for change. Command is special, since the Client who's protected from changes is `Invoker` -- it is decoupled from `ConcreteCommmand` classes. I think that's the classic decoupling you're looking for. Adding new commands will require changing the `Client`, but shouldn't break `Invoker`, who only knows the `Command` abstraction.

I have always thought of the Command pattern as unique, because its main goal seems to be about providing functional requirements: undo, redo, logging, macro-command operations, transactions, etc.

---

#### Edit

Regarding `IReceiver` abstraction and decoupling from `Client` and concrete `Receiver` classes: that is possibly just the Strategy pattern being used with Command. I quoted the original book. Lots of variants of patterns exist (Wikipedia is not always a great reference for patterns because of this).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.If there are multiple receivers with different actions like TV: switchON(), setFirstChannel(); AC:switchOn(),setMinTemp(); MusicPlayer:switchOn(),setMaxVolume().If we have all these requests enqueued. In case any new device like Microwave:switchON(),set30SecTimer() needs to be included then simply objects of Microwave can be encapsulated in the object of TimerCommand and it can simply be added in the queue. This way command pattern can be of good help. Please correct if I am wrong.