# Decouple command from its handler

Tags: design-patterns, command-pattern

[image]My command and handler is in two different layers. I want to my command be as a POCO and know nothing about its handler.
The solution that came in my mind is something like this:

```
public interface ICommand
{
    string GetHandler();
}

public interface ICommandHandler
{
    void HandleCommand(ICommand command);
}

public class XCommand : ICommand
{
    //...
    public string GetHandler()
    {
        return "xh";
    }
}

[Handler("xh")]
public class XCommandHandler : ICommandHandler
{
    public void HandleCommand(ICommand command)
    {
        //handle
    }
}
```

Is this a command pattern?

Comment: This looks like Command/Query Response Separation (CQRS)

Comment: The verb `handle` is a little ambiguous. Your question would be more clear if you gave a concrete example of what handling a command really is. The problem is that in the [`Command`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35295617/1168342) pattern, there is an `execute()` method that performs the command. If that is what you mean by handle, then as @jaco0646 said, it's encapsulated in the command itself. On the other hand (no pun intended), the `Invoker` is totally decoupled from commands in the classic pattern. Invoker 'handles' the commands, but it really just calls `execute()` on them.

Comment: As you said, using "command" and "handle" could be confusing. I have FindRequest and Finder, and I want these objects be decoupled. So I create a FindExecuter, client pass FindRequest to execute. 

I put an image in above post to clarify the problem.

Answer (score 2):

No, the [Command Pattern](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/command) encapsulates "handler" logic into the command object itself, resulting in a black-box that can be executed anywhere. In other words, there is no handler role in the Command Pattern. Its concern is *when* and *how* a command is executed, rather than *who* is performing the execution.

However, there are several other [behavioral patterns](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/behavioral_patterns) to determine who handles a request or event. Notably, the *Chain-of-Command* and *Observer* patterns fit this requirement.

Comment: Thanks, I think as Peter said, it looks like CQRS.